# Fetching Facebook user location and date of birth

Tags: facebook

I am unable to fetch facebook user location and birthday. Does it require any permission to
retrieve this information ?

Can any one tell me how to retrieve this information in PHP?

Can any one tell me the code for accessing birthday and location and how to get permissions

To fetch this data from fbconnect

Thank you.

Comment: Have you read Facebook Graph API ? Did you download Facebook API for PHP ?

Comment: yes i am able to retrieve gender and firsr name and last name but it doesnt retrieve location and birthday.

Comment: `Can any one tell me the code` --- the code is the same as for another fields, but when you show the authentication form you just need to request 2 more permissions

Comment: how can i request those permissions and what are that two permissions can u tel me the code for requesting for those permissions if u r free

Comment: @Naga Raju: I have given a url for you. Obviously you already have authentication, as long as you have access to user's data. So you just need to modify it a little. And no, I will not give a complete code for such case - you need to **read** the link I gave, it is easy to do yourself.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, both birth date and location require additional permissions: `user_birthday` and `user_location` accordingly

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/

Comment: Then how can we get permissions for accessing for these fields

Comment: @Naga Raju: via authentication form: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/